# How to draw 3D images?

Tags: graphics, 3d, drawing

I am working on a simple 3d software renderer but one thing I'm no sure about is how to actually draw it all on the screen. What could I use to draw a wireframed cube ?
I am not asking HOW to write a complete 3D pipeline just the final step, the actual drawing on the screen.

Edit: I think I could do that with SDL.

Comment: Telling us what language, OS, image model, and graphics API you are using would be helpful.

Comment: Currently in c++, I might do it again in Java.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by image model, OS is winxp, not using a graphics api doing it all by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "actual drawing on screen" in Windows XP of your software-rendered wireframe 3D, call [StretchDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a pointer to the array of bytes that represents your pixels. This answer addresses maximum convenience; maximum efficiency is another matter.

Comment: Thanks, but with SDL it even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to project the 3D object onto the 2D screen using a [perspective transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) matrix.

This will generate a set of 2D lines etc. which get drawn in the same way as "normal" 2D lines get drawn.

However, without more information about the language and/or framework you are using, it's not easy to go into any more detail.

Comment: I know that, I have a (almost) complete pipeline, my question is after all of the transformations, what can I use to actually display the final result?

Comment: @monyman_324 - You need a view which is mapped to a window. Exactly how you do that will depend on the OS.

Comment: I am doing it all in c++, not using any framework (I am thinking of maybe use Qt)